# delete all files in a directory that are not in a copy of a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have the following folder structure

```
foo/images
foo/infos
```

infos contains a collection of xml files that describe images from foo/images folder. The naming convention is the following image1.png for images and image1.xml for the descriptors. The problem that I'm trying to solve is the following: **Remove all images that do not have associated descriptors.**

I've been using emacs dired for this for quite some time with great success. However, now I need to do it on a system that doesn't have emacs installed, bash is the only option.

Comment: Sounds like you should be: (i) parse the xml info files (using an XML parser!) to collect the expected image filenames, and (ii) compare that against the actual filenames. Do you have an XML parser available to you? If not, can you get one installed?

Comment: I don't need to parse the xml. xml file name matches image file name. Just the extensions are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

infosdir="foo/infos"
imagesdir="foo/images"

# use a different IFS to allow spaces in filenames
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

# for all images in the images-directory
for pngfullname in ${imagesdir}/*.png; do
 # get the name of the image without the path and without the file-extension
 basename="$(basename ${pngfullname} .png)"
 # if an appropriate xml-file in the infos-directory is missing
 if [ ! -f "${infosdir}/${basename}.xml" ] ; then
   # delete the image
   rm "${pngfullname}"
 fi
done
```

Comment: You should quote all variable expansions to avoid problems caused by file names with spaces., e.g. `basename=$(basename "${pngfullname}" .png)`

Comment: The outer quotes `"$(basename ${pngfullname} .png)"` around `$(...)` are not necessary, but quotes around the variable expansion as shown in my previous comment are important. Test your code with a file created by `touch foo/images/foo\ bar.png`

Comment: @Bodo I did the test ;)

Comment: I didn't notice the IFS manipulation. This fixes problems with space charactes while correct quoting will also correctly handle other special characters. Try `touch foo/images/foo$'\n'bar.png`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For this case, I suggest `find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do …; done` ;) (and better quoting)

Comment: Your script works correct with spaces or newlines in file names if you add quotes around `${pngfullname}` like this`basename="$(basename "${pngfullname}" .png)"`. I'm not sure about the outer quotes around `$(...)`. For me it seems to work with and without the outer quotes, even with `touch foo/images/foo\*.png`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to make a new directory

```
mkdir images_clean
```

Then move the images with existing info to this directory.

```
cd foo/infos
for f in *; do name="${f%.xml}"; mv ../foo/images/"$name".png ../foo/images_clean; done
```

and remove the remaining ones later

```
rm -rf foo/images
```

Comment: This will work, thanks.

Comment: You should also quote `$name` to avoid possible problems caused by file names with spaces.

Comment: @Bodo thanks, updated.